# Is it possible to perform object detection in Azure machine learning, by fetching video from azure blob storage or from a camera feed

Tags: azure, computer-vision, video-streaming, object-detection

I want to perform object detection from input video.
While doing it on local machine, I use openCVs cv2.Videocapture() to get frames from video and tasks like object detection are performed on retrieved frames.
I want to do same thing on Azure machine learning studio.
In AZML we'll need to create a data asset containing video files and then fetch data from there.
Is possible to do this task in AzureML?
If yes, then kindly guide me.

I tried running simple object detection on Azure ML notebook. It is not able to run inside AzureML.
The code is given below,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10
params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1500

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Path of input video
video_file = "./sample_video_1.avi"
# Capture video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect blobs
    keypoints = detector.detect(gray)
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    # Show keypoints
    cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```